# What does 'dance a control run' mean in selection of figure skaters for the Winter Olympics Games?

Tags: meaning

There was the following sentence in the Time magazine article titled, “Plushenko’s retirement is proof he should have quit before Sochi.” It says Evgeni Plushenko should have given way to a younger generation before the Sochi Olympics began:

> “The Russian figure skating association allowed him to dance a
>   “**control run**” for a committee of skating experts less than three weeks
>   before the Games. Although that performance was never shown to the
>   public or the press, the committee ruled that it was enough to give
>   Plushenko a ticket to Sochi.”
>
> http://world.time.com/2014/02/13/plushenko-retirement-sochi-olympics/#ixzz2tFitu1MT

What does “control run” mean? Why is it in quotes? What is the shortest possible paraphrasing of “control run”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Control* here is being used as it would be scientifically, to mean *[a test to verify](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/control?s=ts)* (a scientific experiment) by a parallel experiment or other standard of comparison. [a trial run, a test run]

It is in quotes because it is probably not in popular usage yet (though very much so in studies).

The shortest version would be [*trial*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/trial?s=ts) or *test*.

> The Russian figure skating association allowed him a trial (dance?) for a committee of skating experts...

Answer (score 1):

'A practice performance' is what this means.  The committee watches him skate to see if he is up to standard.